# Where can I run Magik codes?

Tags: smallworld-gis, magik

I did some search on internet and found MDT Professional Edition for Magik programming language but it's not free.

What other Integrated Development Environment (IDE) can be used for running Magik codes?

Is there any free IDE for it?

Comment: When you say "idle", do you mean IDE, Python IDLE or something else?

Comment: I mean IDE (Integrated Development Environment ).

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to update it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: It's been over 5 years since I dealt with Smallworld, but back then I used Emacs...there're packages that integrate the console, code completion and come with some basic utilities. I did work for a company that did SW customizations at the time so some of it may have been proprietary, but a quick google search yielded [Magik Emacs](http://www.magikemacs.com/) and that looks exactly like what I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDT is the only official way of developing Smallworld 5 software. It is the sole development environment promoted by GE.

MDT provides the Administrator Edition for free:
https://www.mdt.net/index.php/mdt-administrator-edition.html

Answer (score 3):

You can install Emacs as an option when installing Smallworld. Emacs, with customization for Smallworld, is provided on the disc. Emacs can be extended with plugins. For example, there are plugins such that you can control your favorite version control system (Git, Subversion, etc) from within Emacs.

MDT is a development environment based on Eclipse, by ASTEC, but is not free.

As far as I know, there are no other (integrated) development environments.

Comment: Thank you @StevenLooman. I have to check if I can find Emacs.

Comment: You can install it as an option when installing Smallworld itself, from the installer on the disc.

Comment: Addition: A new/continuation of the emacs magik-mode can be found here: https://github.com/roadrunner1776/magik
Not written/maintained by myself.